# UDP works on Android 2.3 but not on Android 2.2

Tags: android

I have some code that broadcasts udp packets every second. I have a couple of Android devices sitting, listening. The devices that have 2.3 running pick up the packets every second pretty much without fail. The devices running 2.2 are terrible. Is this a known problem with 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this issue. ( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8407)

The conclusion is that "some manufacturers (& custom ROMs) are filtering out broadcast traffic by default, and some aren't. Take a look at WifiManager.MulticastLock, you may need to aquire the lock in order to receive broadcast traffic: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html"

Here is the proposed solution:

```
WifiManager wifi;
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock ml = wifi.createMulticastLock("just some tag text");
ml.acquire();
```

When the asynctask stops do

```
ml.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I think it would not be a problem because `DatagramSocket` is in use from API level 1 as you can see on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) in the upper right corner. Or are you using another object to handle your connection?

Comment: Hi. I am using DatagramSocket. I did nothing special. All straight out of the examples off the net. When I run the same project on 2.3 I get fantastic results. I run it on a 2.2 and it just does not work.Thanks for the reply though. You would think it being around that long it would be bullet proof. Maybe 2.2 just has issues.